# quiero cambiar un checkbox por una palabra que diga "activo" e "inactivo"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ALguien me puede ayudar...

```
<input  ng-disabled="true" id="lorem3" type="checkbox" name="lorem" ng-model="layout.layoutActInd">
```

Comment: <input  ng-disabled="true" id="lorem3" type="checkbox" name="lorem" ng-model="layout.layoutActInd">

Answer (score 4):

Prueba a usar este código.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function verificar(){
      var checkbox = document.getElementById('box');
      var text = document.getElementById('txt');

      if(document.getElementById('box').checked) {
        $("#txt").text('Activado');
      } else {
        $("#txt").text('Desactivado');
    }
  }
    </script>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="box" onclick="verificar()"><label id="txt"></label>
```

Comment: amm si ya lo checque y si queda el tema es que es con angular y que solo aparezca la palabra activado e inactivado

Answer (score 1):

si entiendo lo que tratas de decir, seria algo asi

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>EJEMPLO:</label>

      <input id="lorem3" type="checkbox" name="lorem" ng-model="layout.layoutActInd">
    <b>{{(layout.layoutActInd == true)? 'activo' : 'Inactivo' ;}}</b>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
      
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es cambiar los valores al tener el check activo o no podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="tucheckbox" name="tucheckbox" id="tucheckbox" ng-init="tucheckbox = 'activo'" ng-true-value="'activo'" ng-false-value="'inactivo'"> {{ tucheckbox == 1 ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo' }}
```